# How to query MySQL JSON column that contains an array of objects

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I have a MySQL (v5.7) database that has a table called *deals* which contains a JSON column called *status*.

*Status* contains data (in *deals* id = 29) in the following format (apologies for the formatting):

```
{
    "trackStatus":
    [
        {
            "date":[],
            "notes":[],
            "value":"0",
            "isChecked":false
        },
        {
            "date":["2019-03-25T17:42:45-04:00"],
            "notes":[],
            "value":4,
            "isChecked":true
         }
    ],
    "nextStatusIndex":0, 
    "currentDealStatus":4
}
```

I am trying to query the `trackStatus` array where `value` = 4`to find out if it`isChecked`.

My understanding from reading the MySQL reference that I need to use the `JSON_EXTRACT` function to get the data.

In following some of the examples, I tested the query as follows to see if I could return `trackStatus`:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(status, '$.trackStatus') 
FROM deals 
WHERE deals.id = 29
```

This works and returns `trackStatus`. However, when I try to expand on this to query within `trackStatus` specifically for `isChecked`, it does not return a value (not null but blank).

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(status, '$.trackStatus', '$.isChecked') 
FROM deals 
WHERE deals.id = 29 AND JSON_EXTRACT(status, '$.trackStatus', '$.value') = 4
```

I have tried a myriad of different queries to the point where I am going in circles.

I realize the issue is with `trackStatus` because if I remove that array, I can query `nextStatusIndex` and it works. However with the array there, it does not.

So I am hoping someone can show me how/if I can query this JSON using MySQL queries (both within `trackStatus` and `nextStatusIndex`) given the way the data is formatted.

Comment: I get what you are trying to do .. But why?  Wouldn't using a scripting language to extract the JSON data you need be far easier?  It seems that you're trying to frame a house with a chainsaw as your only cutting tool.  There are easier, more efficient tools out there ..

Comment: Sure I could do it that way and I am. But I thought since there was the new JSON column that there must be some way of querying this data given all the new JSON functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MySQL 8.0, it would have been possble to turn the inner JSON array to a recordset with [function `JSON_TABLE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html), and then inspect it.

Here is a solution for version 5.7, which relies on [`JSON_SEARCH()` and `JSON_EXTRACT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html).

This query will give you the value of attribute `isChecked` for the (first) element in the `trackStatus` array that has attribute `value` set to `4`:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(
    status, 
    REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
            JSON_SEARCH(status, 'all', '4', '', '$.trackStatus[*].value'), 
        '"', ''), 
    '.value', '.isChecked')
) isCheckedAtValue4
FROM deals WHERE deals.id = 29;
```

With your sample data in [this DB fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8A8UgN3UKpfFhQoVVUxNxk/0), this returns:

```
| isCheckedAtValue4 |
| ----------------- |
| true              |
```

---

**Details**

You can use `JSON_SEARCH` to find the path to the (first) element in array `trackStatus` that has attribute `value` set to `4`:

```
SELECT JSON_SEARCH(status, 'one', '4', '', '$.trackStatus[*].value')
FROM deals 
WHERE deals.id = 29;
```

With your test data, this would typically return: `"$.trackStatus[1].value"`.

We can manipulate the path string point it towards attribute `isChecked` of the same array element. Surrounding double quotes also need to be removed:

```
SELECT REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
        JSON_SEARCH(status, 'one', '4', '', '$.trackStatus[*].value'), 
    '"', ''), 
'.value', '.isChecked'),
FROM deals WHERE deals.id = 29;
```

This returns: `$.trackStatus[1].isChecked`.

Finally, this expression can be be given as an argument to `JSON_EXTRACT()`.

Comment: That is perfect thank you. I must have missed `$.trackStatus[*].value` as an option. Every example I saw was something like `$[*].trackStatus.value`. In addition, you will notice that the value is set to 4 not "4", so for me it still returns null. I verified with your DB Fiddle.  In doing a quick search I see this is as designed and is now a  feature request, so it seems I am stuck with looping through myself. Thanks again!